# need examples for %s in errorformat of vim

Tags: vim, errorformat

this looks like simple question, anyone know what does the %s mean for errorformat option in VIM?
The help text in vim is not clear to me, I need an example to understand it.

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#errorformat: The "%s" conversion specifies the text to search for to locate the error line. The text is used as a literal string. The anchors "^" and "$" are added to the text to locate the error line exactly matching the search text and the text is prefixed with the "\V" atom to make it "very nomagic". The "%s" conversion can be used to locate lines without a line number in the error output. Like the output of the "grep" shell command. When the pattern is present the line number will not be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%s` is for cases where:

- there is no line number in the compiler output (so `%l` can't be used),
- the exact content of the line is available in the compiler output.

For example, the following compiler output:

```
foo/bar.xml:     <foo bar="baz">hamburger</foo>
```

could be consumed with the following `&errorformat`:

```
set errorformat=%f:%\\s%s
```

Comment: I see, so in your example, the %s will capture the "<foo bar="baz">hamburger</foo>", and if you click the "foo/bar.xml:     <foo bar="baz">hamburger</foo>", vim will navigate to "<foo bar="baz">hamburger</foo>" line in foo/bar.xml, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The `s` in `%s` means "search": whatever is matched by `%s` is used as a search pattern within the given file.